# Cisco VPN client connection error: Reason 412: The remote peer is no longer responding

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn-client

The Cisco VPN Client gives the following error message when I try to connect to our VPN:

```
Secure VPN connection terminated locally by the Client  
Reason 412: The remote peer is no longer responding.
```

What could be the cause of this error? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling *IPSec passthrough* on the local network router fixed the problem.